# Declare non-arrow function in Flow

Tags: javascript, function, flowtype, arrow-functions

Is it possible to explicitly declare a parameter as a (non-arrow) function in Flow?

That is, given this situation:

```
function f (g, obj) {
  g.call(obj);
}

f(function() { console.log(typeof this) }, 42)
f(() => { console.log(typeof this) }, 42)
```

`f` only behaves correctly if given a real (non-arrow) function.

I can't see how to declare `f` to require a non-arrow function in Flow.

Comment: The second case is still typesafe though, right?  Given that, there's nothing wrong with someone using what you've specified, it just won't use the `this` being passed as `obj`.

Comment: Well, I don't know the exact definition of "typesafe", but if you can pass an argument to the function which we can determine at compile time is the wrong type of argument - that doesn't seem optimal?

Comment: Also, in my actual non-trivial case, it's very important that you can bind to the function provided.

Comment: Maybe your examples need improving? You can't specify "non-arrow function" as a type because from a type perspective there is no difference. It's just like if you were writing `var self = this; f(function(){ console.log(typeof self); })`, so `this` isn't going to be `42`, but it's not a type error to want to use the outer `this` instead of the one passed to `.call`, it's just writing code that does something different or doesn't use one of its arguments.